# Show result from database as saved with TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE in my HTML Textarea to format content and then save them in MySQL Database. All is working fine. But when I try to get the saved content from database in other page it is showing with all the HTML tags and CSS attributes. What I need is to show the content with same formatting as it was saved.

I am using following code to initilize the TinyMCE in my form.blade.php file.

```
  <script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#requestDescribe'
  });
  </script>
```

Below is the text area where I am using TinyMCE.

```
<textarea required name="requestDescribe" id="requestDescribe" 
cols="30" rows="5" maxlength="600" class="form-control" 
value="{{old('requestDescribe')}}">
```

After saving such type of content is being saved in database.

```
<p><strong>dfg <span style="text-decoration: underline;">fkjg gkjdfhgkfg&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> <em>gdfgf</em></strong></p>
```

When I get data in some other page it shows with all the html and css code like this:

[image: Shows with all html and css code]

I have used PHP stray_tags but it didnt work. Mybe because the code has both html and css. Please Help. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the answer. If you are using PHP (Which is the case with me) so just use echo. :)